# Is this phrase ending a half cadence, imperfect authentic cadence, or neither?

Tags: scales, cadence, phrase, phrasing

I'm working on this for a music theory class.  By my analysis:

1. Song is in key of A major
2. The chord for measure three uses the 4th scale degree, or IV
3. The chord for measure four is the tonic, or I

I'd say that this phrase ends on a plagal cadence (IV to I) but the instructions insist that this is a HC or IAC.  Am I nuts?

[image: system]

Comment: See my answer below. But out of curiosity, have you learned about plagal cadences at this point in the book?

Comment: What book is it from?

Comment: This is a worksheet that the music department uses.  I think it's homebrewed.  The assigned book is Music in Theory and Practice, Tenth Edition (Benward).  I've had a lot of challenges with the coursework in just a month's time.  The book has definitions of musical terms that are more limited than the expected responses on the worksheets.  I did a tutoring session, and even the tutor acknowledged what I'd noticed, and said that she runs into the exact same problems with multiple students.

Comment: The instructor takes no ownership because he's forced to use the worksheets by the department.

Answer (score 4):

There are a lot of problems with the homework question.

But first, here's what they're intending:

1. Look only at the final note (`sol`) and chord (`I`).
2. Is it an HC? No, because the chord would be `E`.
3. Is it an IAC? Yes, because it's a `I` chord, but `do` is not in the soprano.

**As far as the book is concerned, the correct answer is IAC.**

Why the question is problematic:

1. The progression is IV-I, so if it's a cadence at all, it's a plagal cadence, as stated in the question.
2. It's not a cadence. It's just two chords that happen to be the same ones as in a plagal cadence, but there's no sense of "ending" at this point. (Okay, granted, this is more a matter of interpretation/opinion. A reasonable case could be made that it's a cadence.)
3. It's not a phrase. It's the first half of a phrase. Had they included the next four bars and asked the question, then the answer would be HC.

Comment: As you pointed out, the next four bars are not included.  

So I'm not looking at the last two measures to infer a cadence, but ONLY the last measure.

Comment: I have had issues with the way things are worded in our homework for a month now

Comment: @XavierJ - There is only 1 chord in the last measure, so you *have* to look at the last *two* measures to infer the cadence.

Comment: For other readers confused by the terminology like I was, note that American terminology for cadences is totally different from the British (and Commonwealth?) terminology — [Wikipedia has a helpful comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cadence).  In particular, a US *imperfect authentics* cadence is (in UK terminology) a *perfect* cadence that doesn’t end in root position with the tonic in the melody.